# Describe the following set by giving a characteristic property $\{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, ...\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Describe the following set by giving a characteristic property $\{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, ...\}$.  The book I'm reading doesn't describe how to do this, but do I basically need to describe the pattern I see in the set?

Namely that each element is the previous number + 2?

Comment: Hint: Is there any even number in the set?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen no, the set only contains odd numbers.

Comment: Be careful! Since you have the tag "elementary-set-theory" I assume your base set is the natural numbers or perhaps the ordinal numbers. In those cases, 1 is not equal to $n+2$ for any $n$.

Comment: @RoryDaulton sorry!  I'm not sure how to tag these questions.  I'm in a discrete mathematics class and not sure what this should go under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every number in your set is a *positive odd* integer, and the $\ldots$ on the right indicate that the set contains every positive, odd integer.

We usually represent odd numbers by $2n+1$ where $n \in \mathbb N_0.\;$ $\;(\mathbb N_0$ is being used to mean the set of natural numbers (including $0))$.

So we can describe the set using set-builder notation: $$\{2n+1\mid n \in \mathbb N_0\}$$

Comment: So $n$ represents the position in the set?  And since the sets starts at element  $0$, the first element is actually $2(0)+1$ or $1$?

Comment: $n$ starts at zero in the set. Then the first element in the set is $2(0) + 1 = 1$. If you want $n$ to represent an elements position in the set, use $\{2n - 1\mid n \in \mathbb N_{- \{0\}}\}.$ $2n - 1$ is also often used to represent an odd number. Since 2n is an even number (divisible by 2), 2n+1: odd, 2n-1: odd.  Use one, or else use the other.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer that works for ordinal numbers, and not just natural numbers or integers.

Every member of your set equals $n+n+1$ for some (natural number / ordinal number) $n$.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how does $n+n+1$ work for the first element of the set, $1$?

Comment: @inquisitor: Let $n=0$ (or $n={}$ for ordinal numbers). Perhaps I should explain that "natural numbers" in set theory includes the number zero.